# How to convert each number in a num String to an int in C

Tags: c, string, type-conversion

I've been trying to do this problem on [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8)

This is what I've done so far -

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
    char nums[] = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"
    int64_t sum = 1, new_sum = 0;
    int num;
    for(int i = 0; i < 988; i+= 13){
        sum = 1
        for(int j = 0; j < 13; ++j){
            //Converting nums[i] to int and storing it to num here
            sum *= num;
        }
        if(sum > new_sum){
            new_sum = sum;
        }
    }
    printf("%lld", new_sum);
}
```

I don't know how to convert each charNum in the String to an integer, I've tried atoi and sscanf and both of them ask for a char pointer.

I get these errors respectively

```
passing argument to parameter here
int      atoi(const char *); //sum *= atoi(nums[i])
```

```
format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
            sscanf(nums[i], "%d", num);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Uh, no, do it cleverer: Multiply the first 13 digits, then iterate over the rest of the array, divide by the first digit of the 13 digit sub-array and multiply by the digit following the sub-array (this forms the next 13 digit sub-array). You get the numerical digit value from a character in the string by `str[pos] - '0'`.

Comment: `sum` is a pretty bad name for something that should contain a *product* – and why would that always be a *new* product? -> call it what it is (or will be): `max_...`.

Comment: My bad, you're right. I have a habit of naming everything sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just converting a character representing a digit to the digit itself is simply done by

```
int digit = nums[position] - '0';
```

C language guarantees for *any* character set that the digits 0-9 are succeeding one another in exactly that order (which is not necessarily the case for alphabetic characters, see e.g. (in-?) famous EBCDIC).

As I read the problem the maximum can be at *any* location, not only multiples of 13. For this speaks as well that the maximum of four subsequent digits is found at a location where the number of digits preceding is *not* a multiple of four.

Apart from, unless the number if digits is a multiple of 13, your loops would exceed array bounds of `nums`, so undefined behaviour (if not a multiple of 13, then for last iteration of `i` there are less than 13 digits left, but `j` still tries to iterate over all 13 digits).

Fixing both:

```
size_t sequenceLength = 13; // could be a function parameter

size_t len = strlen(nums); // sizeof would include the terminating 0 character!

if(len < sequenceLength)
{
    return 0; // if within a function, else whatever appropriate error handling
}

uint64_t max = 1; // can't have negative values anyway...
for(size_t i = 0; i < sequenceLength; ++i)
{
    max *= nums[i] - '0'; // see above
}
// now we found first possible maximum: the product of first 13 digits

uint64_t num = max;
for(size_t i = sequenceLength; i < len; ++i)
{
    // for next product, we have already included the first 12 digits
    // within the previous product!

    // but there is one surplus digit contained we need to eliminate:
    num /= nums[i - sequenceLength] - '0';

    // now we can include the yet missing one:
    num *= nums[i] - '0';

    // or as a one-liner:
    num = num / (nums[i - sequenceLength] - '0') * (nums[i] - '0');

    // TODO: update maximum, if need be, just as in your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 13

int main() {
    char nums[] = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    int64_t prod = 1, max_prod = 0;
    int num;
    int pos;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof nums; i += N) {
        prod = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            // Converting nums[i] to int and storing it to num here
            num = nums[i + j] - '0';
            prod *= num;
        }
        if (prod > max_prod) {
            max_prod = prod;
            pos = i;
        }
    }
    printf("max product = %ld at %.*s\n", max_prod, N, nums + pos);
}
```

Output:

```
max product = 6270566400 at 4355766896648
```

BTW as the variable name `sum` is misleading, I've changed it to `prod` for product.

Comment: You do not null-terminate the copied string (`strncpy` doesn't do so if the null character is not already contained in the string). Actually `memcpy` would be more efficient, most efficient would be just copying N characters from within the source string: `printf("%.*s", N, nums + pos);`.

Comment: `sum` -> `prod` – so why not `new` -> `max` as well?

Comment: @Aconcagua thank you for the useful suggestions. I do agree. I've updated my answer accordingly. Cheers.

Comment: If `nums` is not a multiple of N you get undefined behaviour for `i+j` being beyond the bounds of `nums` – a problem that existed already in original code. Apart from, I read the question as for N being 2 and input digits being `abcd`, one should check not only `ab` and `cd`, but `bc` as well – which is not done for original as well as your code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want a nuber for each digit (i.e., range 0 to 9)
If yes, the below code should be not too far from what you need:

```
char nums[] = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934969835203... (so long)...";

char *p; 
long lTheTotalCount, lTheNumber;

lTheTotalCount = 0;
for (p=nums ; *p ; p++) {
   lTheNumber = (long)(*p - '0');
   lTheTotalCount += lTheNumber;
};
```

Comment: You are calculating something entirely different...

Comment: Yes, I am. My answer is just to illustrate how to retrieve each numerical digit of the string as an int between 0 and 9.

Comment: Maybe you express that more clearly in the description to the code then? Just for this purpose a single line `int digit = nums[position] - '0';` would have been sufficient, by the way, perhaps more interesting an explanation why this works (C guarantees the digits 0-9 being subsequent).

Comment: You are right - btw doing my best, not always perfect I recognize :-)